# SVM training performance

Tags: performance, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, octave, libsvm

I'm using SVMLib to train a simple SVM over the MNIST dataset. It contains 60.000 training data. However, I have several performance issues: the training seems to be endless (after a few hours, I had to shut it down by hand, because it doesn't respond). My code is very simple, I just call `ovrtrain` on the dataset without any kernel and any special constants:

```
function features = readFeatures(fileName)
   [fid, msg] = fopen(fileName, 'r', 'ieee-be');
   header = fread(fid, 4, "int32" , 0, "ieee-be");

   if header(1) ~= 2051
      fprintf("Wrong magic number!");
   end

   M = header(2);
   rows = header(3);
   columns = header(4);

   features = fread(fid, [M, rows*columns], "uint8", 0, "ieee-be");
   fclose(fid);
   return;
endfunction

function labels = readLabels(fileName)
   [fid, msg] = fopen(fileName, 'r', 'ieee-be');
   header = fread(fid, 2, "int32" , 0, "ieee-be");

   if header(1) ~= 2049
      fprintf("Wrong magic number!");
   end

   M = header(2);

   labels = fread(fid, [M, 1], "uint8", 0, "ieee-be");
   fclose(fid);
   return;
endfunction

labels = readLabels("train-labels.idx1-ubyte");
features = readFeatures("train-images.idx3-ubyte");
model = ovrtrain(labels, features, "-t 0");  % doesn't respond...
```

My question: is it normal? I'm running it on Ubuntu, a virtual machine. Should I wait longer?

Comment: Try training on a smaller subset?

Comment: I've tried to train on a random 10 training examples (just try out that if it works or not). It tooks about 10 seconds to complete. I don't want to train on for example random 100, or 1000 examples, because the final model would be biased, I think....

Comment: Sure, but with, say, 1000 instances you might get a better idea of how much time it takes. What's the dimensionality of your data? Have you tried other parameters?

Comment: With 1000 examples, the training will terminate in...er...minutes.
But I don't get very good accuracy, only 65-70%...

Comment: How many variables do you have? It may be good to use some variable selection or dimensionality reduction techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you took your answer or not, but let me tell you what I predict about your situation. 60.000 examples is not a lot for a power trainer like LibSVM. Currently, I am working on a training set of 6000 examples and it takes 3-to-5 seconds to train. However, the parameter selection is important and that is the one probably taking long time. If the number of unique features in your data set is too high, then for any example, there will be lots of zero feature values for non-existing features. If the tool is implementing data scaling on your training set, then most probably those lots of zero feature values will be scaled to a certain non-zero value, leaving you astronomic number of unique and non-zero valued features for each and every example. This is very very complicated for a SVM tool to get in and extract efficient parameter values.

Long story short, if you had enough research on SVM tools and understand what I mean, you either assign parameter values in the training command before executing it or find a way to decrease the number of unique features. If you haven't, go on and download the latest version of LibSVM, read the ReadME files as well as the FAQ from the website of the tool.

If non of these is the case, then sorry for taking your time:) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue of convergence given the characteristics of your data.

Check the kernel you have as default selection and change it. Also, check the stopping criterion of the package. Additionally, if you are looking for faster implementation, check MSVMpack which is a parallel implementation of SVM.

Finally, feature selection in your case is desired. You can end up with a good feature subset of almost half of what you have. In addition, you need only a portion of data for training e.g. 60~70 % are sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

First of all 60k is huge data for training.Training that much data with linear kernel will take hell of time unless you have a supercomputing. Also you have selected a linear kernel function of degree 1. Its better to use Gaussian or higher degree polynomial kernel (deg 4 used with the same dataset showed a good tranning accuracy).  Try to add the LIBSVM options for -c cost -m memory cachesize -e epsilon tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001). First run 1000 samples with Gaussian/ polynomial of deg 4 and compare the accuracy.